# R mutate() with rowSums()

Tags: r, sum, rowsum

I want to take a dataframe of participant IDs and the languages they speak, then create a new column which sums all of the languages spoken by each participant. The columns are the ID, each language with 0 = "does not speak" and 1 = "does speak", including a column for "Other", then a separate column which specifies what this other language is, "Other.Lang". I want to subset just the columns which have binary values and create this new column with the sums for each participant.

First here is my dataframe.

```
      Participant.Private.ID French Spanish Dutch Czech Russian Hebrew Chinese German Italian Japanese Korean Portuguese Other Other.Lang
    1                5133249      0       0     0     0       0      0       0      0       0        0      0          0     0          0
    2                5136082      0       0     0     0       0      0       0      0       0        0      0          0     0          0
    3                5140442      0       1     0     0       0      0       0      0       0        0      0          0     0          0
    4                5141991      0       1     0     0       0      0       0      0       1        0      0          0     0          0
    5                5143476      0       0     0     0       0      0       0      0       0        0      0          0     0          0
    6                5145250      0       0     0     0       0      0       0      0       0        0      0          0     1      Malay
    7                5146081      0       0     0     0       0      0       0      0       0        0      0          0     0          0
```

Here is the structure:

```
    str(part_langs)
    
    grouped_df [7 x 15] (S3: grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
     $ Participant.Private.ID: num [1:7] 5133249 5136082 5140442 5141991 5143476 ...
     $ French                : num [1:7] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     $ Spanish               : num [1:7] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
     $ Dutch                 : num [1:7] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     $ Czech                 : num [1:7] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     $ Russian               : num [1:7] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     $ Hebrew                : num [1:7] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     $ Chinese               : num [1:7] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     $ German                : num [1:7] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     $ Italian               : num [1:7] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
     $ Japanese              : num [1:7] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     $ Korean                : num [1:7] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     $ Portuguese            : num [1:7] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     $ Other                 : num [1:7] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
     $ Other.Lang            : chr [1:7] "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
     - attr(*, "groups")= tibble [7 x 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
      ..$ Participant.Private.ID: num [1:7] 5133249 5136082 5140442 5141991 5143476 ...
```

I thought that this should work:

```
    num <- part_langs %>%
      mutate(num.langs = rowSums(part_langs[2:14]))
    num
```

However, I keep getting this **error message:**

```
    Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `num.langs`.
    x Input `num.langs` can't be recycled to size 1.
    i Input `num.langs` is `rowSums(part_langs[2:14])`.
    i Input `num.langs` must be size 1, not 7.
    i The error occurred in group 1: Participant.Private.ID = 5133249.
```

What is really strange is that when I try to create a **simplified version** of this problem to create a **reproducible example**, it works fine.

First I create a dataset.

```
    test <- matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, "",
                   2, 1, 0, 1, 0, "",
                   3, 0, 0, 0, 1, "Chinese"), ncol = 6, byrow=TRUE)
    
    test<-as.data.frame(test)
    
    colnames(test) <- c("ID", "English", "French", "Italian", "Other", "Other.Lang")
    
    str(test)
```

Converting binary columns to numeric:

```
    test$ID <- as.numeric(test$ID)
    test$English <- as.numeric(test$English)
    test$French <- as.numeric(test$French)
    test$Italian <- as.numeric(test$Italian)
    test$Other <- as.numeric(test$Other)
```

Here's the same code as above, but with this simplified data set.

```
    num <- test %>%
      mutate(num.langs = rowSums(test[2:5]))
    num
```

Here is the output. It works exactly as I want:

```
    "ID","English","French","Italian","Other","Other.Lang","num.langs"
     1,     1,        1,       0,        0,        "",         2
     2,     1,        0,       1,        0,        "",         2
     3,     0,        0,       0,        1,     "Chinese",     1
```

So I know I have screwed up somewhere in my real data, but I can't understand where. Could anyone advise?

Comment: The difference in result might be due to the fact that `part_langs` is `grouped_df [7 x 15] (S3: grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)`. Maybe `ungroup`, like so:  `library(dplyr); part_langs <- part_langs %>% ungroup`?

Comment: Or avoid the using mutate and and try `part_langs$num.langs = rowSums(part_langs[2:14])`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann You were right! Adding in the ungroup code and running it again fixes this problem. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Dave2e You're absolutely right, this is by far the most sensible way to approach it...but I was frustrated with not knowing why mutate() wasn't working the way I thought it ought to, and I had to understand it first. I appreciate your suggestion too.

Comment: If it helped I'm going to add this comment as an asnwer hoping you will accept/upvote it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in result might be due to the fact that `part_langs` is a grouped dataframe, as can be seen from the output of `str`shown in your post:

```
grouped_df [7 x 15] (S3: grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame).
```

If this is the reason, then `ungroup` first and rerun your code:

```
library(dplyr)
part_langs <- part_langs %>% ungroup
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach which relies more on `dplyr`would be to use `rowwise` and `c_across`:

```
test %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(num.lang = sum(c_across(English:Other)))
```